# No module named dbus.glib during Jhbuild setup?

Tags: jhbuild

I am trying to set up jhbuild environment on https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome

As I tried to install dependencies and ran `$jhbuild sysdeps --install`, I see an error of `ImportError: No module named dbus.glib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Fedora 25, I was able to satisfy this dependency with the `dbus-python-devel` package, I suspect this should also work for previous versions (note that this package worked for the default Python 2.7 package, I do not see an equivalent devel package for Python 3). For apt-based distros, I believe the equivalent package would be `python-dbus-dev`.